# How to detect if a view is being touched if the press down originates outside of that view?

Tags: java, android

I want to touch down on the view of object B and swipe to ie. object 3 where I release it. It needs to register that is has been released at object 3. I thought to give object 3 a OnTouchListener as well but that ontouchlistener is not called since it started outside of its view. I dont think a global ontouchlistener working back to coordinates will work since its all in a ScrollView. I tried several callback but none seem to work and I can't find an answer to this.
So, How to detect if a view is being touched if the press down originates outside of that view?

[image]

Comment: You probably want to implement *Drag and Drop* instead of rolling your own solution: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cactustictacs suggested the Drag and Drop works great for this.
Basically:

1. Set a onTouchListener on objects B view that starts a drag action.
2. Extend DragShadowBuilder and create a custom background/shadow for the dragged object. (Transparent drawable for me)
3. Add data of object B to the drag action
4. Set Object 1 2 3 views as drop zones by implementing onDragListeners.